# Fontspec SizeFeatures and recursive font definition

Tags: xetex, fontspec, fontsize

I suspect this isn't valid code, but the docs are ambiguous.

fontspec is loaded with `\fontspec[<font features>]{fontname}`. BoldFont is included in "font features". Then I should be able to recursively define:

```
\setmainfont[SizeFeatures={
{Size={-8},BoldFont=Arial},
{Size=8-}}]{Hoefler Text}
```

But this gives

```
(fontspec) The following font options are not recognised:
(fontspec)     BoldFont=Arial
```

Not allowed or there's a way around it? My hopes were to make the **whole** font definitions in this way (with `BoldFeatures={SizeFeatures=...}` again and so on).

A minimal working file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[SizeFeatures={
{Size={-8},BoldFont=Arial},
{Size=8-}}]{Hoefler Text}

\begin{document}
Normal text\
{\small \textbf{Small bold}}\\
\end{document}
```

Edit: Using Gentoo/Linux, Texlive-2010

Comment: (Wanted to add the tag "sizefeatures" but not allowed to new members, could someone create it?)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! I think `fontspec` is precise enough for a tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

define first a bold font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[BoldFont=Arial Bold,
  SizeFeatures={
  {Size={-8},BoldFont=Arial Bold},
  {Size=8-}}]{Hoefler Text}

\begin{document}
Normal text\\

{\small \textbf{Small bold}}\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: (fontspec) The following font options are not recognised:
    (fontspec)     BoldFont=Arial Bold

    For immediate help type H <return>.
     ...                                              
                                                  
    l.7   {Size=8-}}]{Hoefler Text}

Comment: I get the above with your code, or other fonts. (XeLatex is working fine with other samples)

Comment: are you running Linux or Windows?

Comment: Sorry Linux/Gentoo, TexLive 2010

Comment: 2010 is a bit old for the package `fontspec`. Can yiou upgrade to 2011?

Comment: I booted on Windows to try 2011 and it worked :). Thanks